xpath for multiple nodes selecting substring have an invalid token
xml document containing comment in comments node as:
<Comments>
    <Comment>09/28/2021 22:21:31user1 [1] file uploaded </Comment>
    <Comment>09/28/2021 22:22:47user2 [2] file scanned</Comment>
    <Comment>09/28/2021 22:23:15user3 [3] Backed up before edit</Comment>
    <Comment>09/28/2021 22:23:39user3 [4] file edited </Comment>
</Comments>

the above mention comment contains Timestamp, userid and comment
want to retrieve that separately through xpaths epressions:

for timestamp: /Comments/Comment/fn:substring(text(), 0, 20)
for user: /Comments/Comment/fn:substring(text(), 20, string-length(substring-before(text(), "[")) - 20)
for comment: /Comments/Comment/fn:substring-after(text(), "]")

above mentioned xpaths worked fine on the xpath tester
but returning error of invalid token in my C# code:
var list = new List<XmlNodeList>();
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes(strExpression); 
if (nodes.Count > 0)
{
    list.Add(nodes);
}


tried node iterator as well but same results
XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;
NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression);
while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
{
    if (NodeIter.Current != null)
        xpathValue.Add(NodeIter.Current.Value);
};


Please show your strExpression, so we can make sure it's a case of missing escaping or something.

The used syntax is XPath 2 or higher while all Microsoft implementations support only XPath 1.0. So you will need to look into third party solutions for XPath 2 or higher like https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPath2 or like Saxon HE .NET https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE (for .NET framework, doesn't work with .NET Core/cross platform .NET (e.g. 6,7,8..)) or commercial packages like SaxonCS or XmlPrime or my home grown port of Saxon-HE to modern cross platform .NET with packages like https://www.nuget.org/packages/SaxonHE10Net31XQuery.

@PalleDue passes these strExpressions
for timestamp: /Comments/Comment/fn:substring(text(), 0, 20)
for user: /Comments/Comment/fn:substring(text(), 20, string-length(substring-before(text(), "[")) - 20)
for comment: /Comments/Comment/fn:substring-after(text(), "]")

@MartinHonnen thanks for the help. So basically, there is no way out to achieve this in .NET Core?

There are libraries that work with .NET Core and support XPath  2 or later, I think https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPath2#supportedframeworks-body-tab should do, as should do any of my cross compilations of Saxon HE 10 or 11 or 12 to .NET Core with a modern IKVM version, although Saxon has its own API, not the same as the MS one. XmlPrime or SaxonCS also work with cross platform .NET but a commercial packages. but they certainly do support XPath 3.1.

Note also that in the substring() expression, positions count from 1, not 0.

Here is how you can do it with Saxon HE, if you want to do it with cross platform .NET (e.g. .NET 6 or 7 or 8) you can use the NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/SaxonHE10Net31Api and use code like
using Saxon.Api;

var xmlSource = @"<Comments>
    <Comment>09/28/2021 22:21:31user1 [1] file uploaded </Comment>
    <Comment>09/28/2021 22:22:47user2 [2] file scanned</Comment>
    <Comment>09/28/2021 22:23:15user3 [3] Backed up before edit</Comment>
    <Comment>09/28/2021 22:23:39user3 [4] file edited </Comment>
</Comments>";

var processor = new Processor(false);

var docBuilder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();

docBuilder.BaseUri = new Uri("urn:from-string");

var xdmDoc = docBuilder.Build(new StringReader(xmlSource));

var xpathCompiler = processor.NewXPathCompiler();

var timestamps = xpathCompiler.Evaluate("/Comments/Comment/substring(., 0, 20)", xdmDoc);

foreach (var timestamp in timestamps)
{
    Console.WriteLine(timestamp);
}

and get e.g.
09/28/2021 22:21:31
09/28/2021 22:22:47
09/28/2021 22:23:15
09/28/2021 22:23:39

If you want to use .NET framework use the package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE instead.
[NB: I simplified your sample XPath expression slightly as there is no need to use the fn prefix nor the need to select down to a text node with text(). But Saxon is a bit picky, also, if you want to use the fn prefix you need to add xpathCompiler.DeclareNamespace("fn", "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"); before evaluating the XPath expression(s).]
